# An exercise from the handbook of set-theoretic topology

Tags: general-topology, set-theory

This is an exercise from the handbook of set-theoretic topology (**Exercise 13.3**):

> Assume $\mathfrak b=\mathfrak c$. Construct a first countable separable zero-dimensional locally compact pseudocompact space which is not countably compact but which is $\omega_1$ compact,.i.e., which has no uncountable closed discrete subset.

Here is a Hint from this book. First construct a space first countable zero-dimensional locally compact space $X$ with underlying set $\mathfrak c$ such that $D=\{\xi: \omega\le \xi < \omega + \omega\}$ is a closed discrete set of cluster points of $\omega$ and such that each countably infinite subset of $X\setminus D$ has a cluster point.

I don't how to begin it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Paul, Perhaps it'd help me and other readers if you add some comments explaining some of your adjectives. For example: I believe that b stands for least size of an unbounded family in $\omega^{\omega}$ but I do not know what pseudocompact means and I am too lazy to google it up.